# Obtain span HTML values to operate as array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, getelementbyid

Actually i have an HTML students form with notes, everytime you click the button who redirects to `anadirNota()`. Obtain the value from the input `txtNota` and add to the span `spanNotas`. And when you click on `anadirAlumno()` button, add the values of the form to a new row of the table but use the `spanNotas` (as array) to calculate whith the method `obtenerMedia()`.
**My Question is:** How i can get de spanNotas elements as Array of Ints to operate?

**EXAMPLE:**

Nombre: Al    
Apellido: Umno    
Notas: [2, 6, 8]

When i click de "añadir alumno" button inserts the row:

```
Nombre | Apellidos | Media
Al     | Umno      | 5,33
```

HTML Code:

```
 <body>
        Nombre:<input id="txtNombre" type="text" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Apellido:<input id="txtApellido" type="text" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Notas:&nbsp;[<span id="spanNotas"></span>]
        <br/>
        Nota:<input id="txtNota" type="text" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="Añadir nota" onclick="anadirNota()"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Añadir alumno" />
        <br/><br/>
        <table id="tablaAlumnos">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Media</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

Javascript code:

```
    function anadirNota() {
        var nota = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtNota").value);
        console.log(nota);
        if(!isNaN(nota)) {

            var listaNotas = document.getElementById("spanNotas").innerHTML;
            console.log(listaNotas);
            listaNotas += nota;
            console.log(listaNotas);
            document.getElementById("spanNotas").innerHTML=listaNotas+", ";
        } else {
            alert("El valor del campo nota no es válido")
        }
    }

    function anadirAlumno() {

        var nombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre").value;
        var apellido = document.getElementById("txtApellido").value;
        var notas = document.getElementById("spanNotas").innerHTML;

        if(nombre != "" || apellido != "" || notas.isEmpty ) {

            var Alumno1 = new Alumno(nombre, apellido, notas);
            var notaMedia = Alumno1.obtenerMedia();

            console.log(Alumno1);

            var table = document.getElementById("tablaAlumnos");
            fila = table.insertRow(table.length);
            fila.insertCell (0).innerHTML=nombre;
            fila.insertCell (1).innerHTML=apellido;
            fila.insertCell (2).innerHTML=notaMedia;
        } else {
            alert("Los datos del alumno no son correctos")
        }
    }

    var Alumno = function(nombre, apellido, notas)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.notas = notas;

        this.obtenerMedia = function() {
            var media = 0;

            for(i = 0; i < this.notas.length; i++)
                media += this.notas[i];

            media /= this.notas.length;
            return media.toFixed(2);
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is, your `listaNotas` is a string. define a global variable what is an `Array()`; and instead `+=` use `push()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **lolka_bolka** said: listaNota contains a string (e.g "2, 4, 5") so make it an array by splitting at each `,`. The `.map()` function turns all parts into numbers. At last step the array is converted back to a string with `.join()`;

```
if(!isNaN(nota)) { 
    var listaNotas = document.getElementById("spanNotas").innerHTML;
        console.log(listaNotas);
    var notaArray = listaNotas.split(',').map(function(n) {return parseFloat(n);})
        console.log(notaArray);
    notaArray.push(nota);
        console.log(notaArray);
    document.getElementById("spanNotas").innerHTML = notaArray.join(', ');
}
```